# VBA Add sum formula across tables in multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have the below macro for taking a master list of data and splitting it into multiple tabs based on a unique name in column A.  This works as intended, but I'm trying to figure a way to find the last row in the new tables and add a sum formula at that row for each column, from columns "L" through "Z".  If possible I would also like to format it based on specific row in my Template tab.  Any help would be appreciated as I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Thanks everyone,
Eric

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
'Create copies of a template sheet using text on a master sheet in a specific column
'Sheetname strings are corrected using the UDF below
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
Dim shNAMES As Range, Nm As Range, NmSTR As String, NR As Long

With ThisWorkbook                                               'keep focus in this workbook
    Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")                            'sheet to be copied
    wasVISIBLE = (wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible)              'check if it's hidden or not
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible      'make it visible

    Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Master")                            'sheet with names
                                                                'range to find names to be checked
    Set shNAMES = wsMASTER.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlFormulas)     'or xlFormulas

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                          'speed up macro
    For Each Nm In shNAMES                                      'check one name at a time
        NmSTR = FixStringForSheetName(CStr(Nm.Text))            'use UDF to create a legal sheetname
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & NmSTR & "'!A1)") Then       'if sheet does not exist...
            wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)           '...create it from template
            ActiveSheet.Name = NmSTR                            '...rename it
        End If
        With .Sheets(NmSTR)
            NR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            wsMASTER.Range("B1:B1").Copy
            .Range("A" & NR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            Nm.Resize(, 500).Copy .Range("A" & NR)
        End With
    Next Nm

    wsMASTER.Activate                                           'return to the master sheet
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden       'hide the template if necessary
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                           'update screen one time at the end
End With

MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub


Function FixStringForSheetName(shSTR As String) As String

'replace each forbidden character with something acceptable
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, ":", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "?", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "*", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "/", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "\", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "[", "(")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "]", ")")

'sheet names can only be 31 characters
    FixStringForSheetName = Trim(Left(shSTR, 31))

End Function
```

Comment: [Find last row, column or last cell]([link](http://example.com))

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I would use:

```
Sub checkCols()

ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
urName = Cells(1, ur).Address
MsgBox (ur)
MsgBox (urName)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i'm not sure what this is supposed to be doing or how to apply this to do the task I'm asking.

Comment: UsedRange is unreliable.